# Display custom field value into content with hyperlink

Tags: custom-field, metabox

The following code helped me to display the "Custom Field" value in the `the_content` section.

But I need a help to make it to show as a hyperlink.

Here is the code:

```
function wpa_content_filter( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if( $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'demo_link', true ) ) {
        return $content . $meta;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpa_content_filter', 10 );
```

For example:

If I give the following custom field value:

```
demo_link = http://www.example.com
```

The code result would be like

```
http://www.example.com
```

But I need the link to be clickable.

Can anyone please help on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for...

```
function wpa_content_filter( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if( $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'demo_link', true ) ) {
        return $content.' <a href="'.$meta.'">'.$meta.'</a>';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpa_content_filter', 10 );
```

Comment: no luck with this code! It didn't work. It prints the same value.

Comment: updated my answer, does that do the trick?

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer.

I tried, it makes the link as a hyperlink. But the target link is showing current page and .meta value.

Example: 

It returns - http://www.example.com (It makes the hyperlink)

http://www.example.com/.$meta. (It shows the current page + .$meta. value)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Could you please elaborate and perhaps add to your question?

Comment: @vancy I guess you just forgot to add ´http://´ to the link you have set as meta value.

Comment: Fantastic @vancy glad we could find an answer! :)